# Динамическо добавление элементов в массив

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть Input через который добавляются элементы списка с данными.
Как сделать, чтобы после ввода N-количества элементов, эти элементы без вмешательства пользователя добавились в массив.

```
$('#new').keyup(function(e){ console.log(e.keyCode);

if (e.keyCode==13){
    $('#main').show();
    $('#footer').show();
    $('#list').append('<li>\
            <div class="task">\
              <label class="text"><input class="toggle" type="checkbox">'+$(this).val()+'</label>\
                <button class="destroy"></button>\
            </div>\
       </li>');
    // Очистка Input
    $('#new').val('');
}
});
```

// Добавление в массив

```
$('li').ready( function () {
   var tasks = [];
   $('label.text').each(function() {
      tasks.push($(this).text());
   })
});
```

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы при каждом добавлении `li`, в массив добавлялся текст из добавленного `label`?

Comment: да, чтобы при добавлении 'li' добавлялся текст из  'label'

Comment: А почему бы при создании не добавлять текст?

Comment: не совсем понял, что вы имеете ввиду

Comment: Когда Вы создаёте `li` в обработчике `keyup`, добавляйте сразу и в массив нужный текст.

Comment: можете показать в моем коде, как именно надо реализовать

Comment: Как-то так: https://jsfiddle.net/9Lf9a9qp/

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let tasks = [];

$('#new').keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
   let $this = $(this);
    $('#list').append('<li>\
              <div class="task">\
                <label class="text"><input class="toggle" type="checkbox">' + $this.val() + '</label>\
                  <button class="destroy">Destroy</button>\
              </div>\
         </li>');
         
    tasks.push($this.val());
    // Очистка Input
    $('#new').val('');
  }
});

// Для демонстрации; нажмите кнопку, чтобы увидеть все задачи
$('#showTasks').on('click', function(){
 console.info(`Your tasks: %s`, tasks.toString());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='new' /> | <input type='button' id='showTasks' value='Показать задачи' />
<br />
<ul id='list'></ul>
```

Comment: как можно реализовать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку Destroy, удалялся необходимый элемент массива

Comment: @LoranDeMarcus, это уже совсем другая история, т. е. вопрос.